# Convert string to mpz_t in C

Tags: c, string, type-conversion, gmp

Is there a method to convert a `string`, or in my case a `char array`, to the `mpz_t` type from gmplib. Is there something similar to the `sscanf` function? Anything for the C programming language would be relevant.

Comment: can you give an example what you want to achieve ? e.g. `char number[]="1234"; mpz_t n; mpz_set_str(n, my_number,10); ` This will assign given number using base 10 to n . check here https://www.cs.colorado.edu/~srirams/classes/doku.php/gmp_usage_tutorial

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the online manual: https://gmplib.org/manual/Assigning-Integers.html#Assigning-Integers

The function `mpz_set_str` is probably what you are looking for.